# Git, how to find all commits on a file after version X

Tags: git, commit

Can I find list of commits in a given file after version v4.0?

Comment: Is "v4.0" either a tag or a branch?

Answer (score 2):

`git log v4.0.. -- file` assuming `v4.0` is a tag.